# Change payload within Spring integration Filter

Tags: spring-integration

I am writing a filter with Spring Integration.

In this filter I check a set of preconditions. If any precondition is not satisfied, I would need to change message payload (or even header) to add the set of actions to be done by the user to satisfied it and return it to the user over the discart channel.

I could use a service activator but I think the filter would more descriptive in this case.

What is the cleanest way to make it?

This is  a sort of pseudocode:

```
@Filter
public boolean checkEventPreconditions(Message<?> messageIn)
{
    //Here I am returning the set of actions to satisfied preconditions
    List<Integer> actionsId = returnActions();

    if(actionsId.isEmpty())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        //Here I need to add actionsId to the message
        return false;
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No, don't mix concerns: filter just has to check if send message further or discard it.
To change the message is a responsibility of transformer.
So, what you want to do should be placed within **discard** flow.

Comment: The problem is that I know whether the message should be discarted or not when I make the returnActions method (involves execution of groovy scripts). If I pass the last section to the discard flow I would need to execute the groovy scripts again...

Comment: So, just place the result of `returnActions()` to the Message's Headers and reuse the value in the filter and discrad flow.

Comment: OK. this will be a better approach. Thanks!